# Prove for any group $G$, the function $f:G \rightarrow G$ defined by $f(x)=e$ is a homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra

> QUESTION: Prove for any group $G$, the function $f:G \rightarrow G$ defined by
> $f(x)=e$ is a homomorphism

I said:

> Let $G$ be a group, and let the function $f:G \rightarrow G$ defined
> by $f(x)=e$ then for $x,y \in G$ $f(xy)=ee=f(x)f(y)$. Then $f$ is a
> homomorphism.

I feel that my answer was too short, and normally when my answer is short I feel I'm missing something. So i looked in Pinter's abstract algebra for the definition of homomorphism and I don't see anything else to work with since Pinter said

> If $G$ and $H$ are groups, a homomorphism from $G$ to $H$ is a function $f: G \rightarrow H$ such that for any two elements $a$ and $b$ in $G$
>
> $$ f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$$

and we are given that $f$ is a function, so all we need left to show is $f(ab)=f(a)f(b)$

Am I missing something?

Comment: Strictly speaking, you should say $f(xy)=e=ee=f(x)f(y)$.

Comment: So $xy$ should be looked at as $(xy)$ instead of $(x)(y)$? In other words, $xy$ is one element.

Comment: Yes, $f($anything$)=e$, and here your "anything" is $xy$.

Comment: Great. I was a bit confused about that, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @Shalop Please consider converting your comment into an answer, so that this question gets removed from the [unanswered tab](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/3138). If you do so, it is helpful to post it to [this chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9141) to make people aware of it (and attract some upvotes). For further reading upon the issue of too many unanswered questions, see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143113), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1148) or [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/9868).